# isItemChecked always returns the opposite of what it is supposed to when inside an onItemClickListener?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapterview

I currently have a `ListView`, which activates a Contextual `ActionBar` in the `ListView`'s `OnItemLongClickListener`.

I am trying to make it so that items can be selected by clicking on them, but only when the Contextual `ActionBar` is up.

The problem is, when I check `isItemChecked()` , so as to toggle the item's selection state, it always returns the opposite of what it is supposed to.

Here is how I've implemented the `OnItemClickListener`:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (mActionMode != null){
            list.setItemChecked(position, !list.isItemChecked(position));
        }
        else{
            list.setItemChecked(position, false);
        }

    }

});
```

**EDIT:** This is pretty bizzare.. this code *toggles* the selection state:

```
list.setItemChecked(position, list.isItemChecked(position));
```

What is going on!?

**EDIT 2:** Ah, it looks like android is automatically checking and unchecking each item on its own... is there any way to change this behavior and handle it myself?

Comment: We need to understand what is in the mActionMode method, as it is triggering whether the checkbox should be checked or not. Are you able to include the code for the `mActionMode()` method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here is the documentation for `setItemChecked` method:
Sets the checked state of the specified position

in the line

```
list.setItemChecked(position, !list.isItemChecked(position));
```

you are explicitly setting it to the opposite of what `isItemChecked` returns by negating  the secoend arguement in the statement